# Why would a thermostat not be able to maintain temperature in an apartment with central water heating?

Tags: thermostat, heating

I live in an apartment with central water heating and a wall mounted Honeywell T822K1034 thermostat. I've had this thermostat before, and as far as I understand it works on the principles:

1. It has a spiral thermometer to measure the indoor temperature
2. When the indoor temperature falls a few degrees below a target temperature threshold set by the control lever, the thermostat completes a circuit in the wall, opening a valve in the unit and letting heat in
3. Once a the temperature rises above a few degrees higher than the target temperature, the circuit is broken and the valve is shut off, stopping the heat

[image: T822K1034 wall mounted thermostat]

However in my unit, it's failing to maintain the set temperature, and instead acts as a manual valve switch where you move the control lever to the left to turn it off and to the right to turn it off.

[image]

Based on this behavior, I'd guess that the wires are switched. Opening it up, red is connected to R (power) and white is connected to W (heat). Assuming that red is hot and white is neutral this seems to be wired correctly?

So far maintenance says there isn't a problem. They claim that the thermostat can't maintain an indoor temperature because "the boilers temperature is controlled by the outdoor temperature". This doesn't seem relevant to me, since the point is to control not the temperature of the heated water, but the flow through the pipes into the unit.

What am I missing here? Is it possible to have this thermostat maintain an indoor temperature or do I have to manually switch it on and off when it gets too hot/cold inside?

EDIT: This is in Ontario, Canada

Comment: Boiler water temperature will determine _how long_ it takes to heat your apartment to the desired set point, not whether it will heat at all. I'm _really_ not an expert here, but it sounds to me like your thermostat isn't working correctly and that maintenance doesn't want to fix it. I'd suggest talking to a few of your neighbors to see if they're having the same issue, and if so, present a united front to management. Also, management may not be aware that maintenance is putting this off, so you may want to contact someone else...

Comment: Your question is written very clearly but can you confirm that the heat comes on when you move the temp control to the left (lower numbers) and turns off, when you move the control to right (higher numbers)?  If so, then something is definitely backwards.  Also, what's going on with that black wire?  I can't make out whether it is connected to anything.

Comment: You should probably confirm your location.  I'm guessing you are not in the US given that the temperatures are in Celsius.  But assuming that's not a factor: red is power, white is the connection to the heat source.  Black appears to be C or common and I'm reading that it is usually associated with heat pumps.  It might not matter here but is this a forced water system or a boiler?

Comment: @FreeMan - I think this is the case. I'm half a mind to swap the wires on my own just to try it out, but I'm not confident that switching the unit's breakers off will turns off power to the thermostat

Comment: @JimmyJames - Yes, the heat comes on when the temp control is lower and off when it's higher. This is what makes me think the wiring is flipped. The black wire is just tucked into a hole and not connected to anything. It has no cover and the copper is visible at the end of the wire.

Update the location to Ontario, Canada

Comment: If I had to guess, the wires are installed according to the thermostat manual, but the boiler valve is old and has the opposite configuration of what you would expect, so the wires need to be flipped.

Comment: @rovyko It appears to be wired correctly, at least red/white.  I doubt it would work at all if they were switched somehow.  You could damage the thermostat or the furnace if you flip them.  I once fried a Taco pump doing it wrong.

Comment: The thing is that red ([from here](https://www.aireserv.com/about/blog/2020/february/the-thermostat-wire-color-code-you-need-to-know/)) should always be hot and white should switch based on the state of the thermostat.  Do you have a volt-meter?  You should definitely check that before you switch anything.

Comment: If your maintenance people can't understand that moving the setting to cold brings on the heat and setting it to hot turns it off is not how thermostats are supposed to work, they are idiots or lying.  Call management.

Comment: It seems almost like somehow it's setup for control A/C instead of heat.  Does the thermostat have a heat/cool switch?  That doesn't seem possible, though.

Comment: Your comment made me take a second look at the manual and I think I found the problem. Terminal W is "Heat Relay" but Terminal Y is "Cool relay OR open hot water valve".

It doesn't solve the problem of maintaining the temperature, but at least it's a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bang-Bang Controls 101

> Based on this behavior, I'd guess that the wires are switched. Opening it up, red is connected to R (power) and white is connected to W (heat). Assuming that red is hot and white is neutral this seems to be wired correctly?

*Close*.  These are 24-volt "low voltage" controls.  Which means hot and neutral are not applicable terms here, *but you're on the right track*.  The standard wires in 24-volt systems are:

R = 24V supply from transformer (hot-ish)
C = 24V return to transformer (neutral-ish)
W = call for heat
G = call for blower only (in forced-air systems)
Y = call for air conditioning

Sometimes the A/C unit has its own 24V transformer, that's why there's R(h) and R(c). You can see those unpopulated sites right in the plastic molding of your thermostat.   B and O are heat pump things.

Back down in the guts of the system, there's an actuator (gas solenoid valve; Taco water valve) that is wired to W and C, completing the circuit. The thermostat doesn't get C unless it is a Nest. Note the spare wire for if that ever happens.

> So far maintenance says there isn't a problem. They claim that the thermostat can't maintain an indoor temperature because "the boilers temperature is controlled by the outdoor temperature". This doesn't seem relevant to me, since the point is to control not the temperature of the heated water, but the flow through the pipes into the unit.

You got it.  At some "low" setpoint, the thermostat goes BANG! on. And at a high setpoint it goes "BANG!" off.  But think about it: A Bang-Bang controlled heater, *when it runs*, must run hard enough enough to overcome the worst arctic chill possibly expected in this locale.

So in your mind, you are expecting your building to deliver Very Hot water, hot enough to overcome the worst possible Polar Vortex, and on a temperate day of say 13C (55F) you'd run maybe 5% duty cycle. You don't dare shunt R and C (set thermostat to max), or you'd be smoked out of the apartment!  ***That's your expectation***.

### And.... that's obsolete.

Except the Bang-Bang approach is obsolete.  It made sense when gas or electricity was cheaper than smart controls. But now, it's no problem running a furnace at variable speeds - and this enables technologies like *condensing furnaces* which gain 15-20% efficiency over Bang-Bang units, or VFD-controlled heat pumps which are quieter by a lot.

In this scenario, the furnace runs pretty much continuously at the lowest setting that will do the job. It figures out what that is by looking at outside temperature and from that, estimating how much thermal loss your house is having through insulation and leakage.

In that light, what maintenance said *explains everything*.  Your building has converted to a condensing boiler, which runs the system hot water at a variable temperature based on outside temperature. It is trying to supply exactly the right temperature to your radiators to compensate for thermal losses through the insulation.

So if your apartment had no thermostat at all, one could reasonably expect apartment temperature to follow the weather, but stay halfway reasonable.  You can try this for yourself simply by setting the thermostat to "MAX".

However, if that results in an apartment that is warmer than you'd like, the thermostat allows you to do BANG-BANG control of that already-adjusted heat.  Because the heat is close to optimum already, the duty cycle will be much longer - say, 90% on a 13C (55F) day.

This also imposes a simple maximum on how hot it's possible to make the apartment.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, unfortunately the "right temperature" supplied to my radiators is way too hot, leaving the unit at around 28C ambient if the valve is left open continuously. Since the valve IS controllable (I'm able to turn the heat on/off) and the radiator output is hotter than ideal temperature, the same principles apply. The thermostat should simply switch the valves less frequently, since the incoming heat approximates the ideal unit temperature.

So far I've left the window slightly open in the bedroom, but I still have to fiddle with it daily to keep the unit pleasant.

Comment: @rovyko ...well that's how they *should* set it up. Have it run a little hotter than ideal, so you can turn it down with the bang-bang thermostat. It sounds like your thermostat is either broken or not very accurate.  FYI they're like $40. Not even.

Comment: Yes I just misread the last part of your answer

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to pick holes in this theory, as much as you like. I'm just guessing… & I'm using the answer space for illustrations.

I'm starting by assuming some physical relationship between the "knob" & the unit marked 'Precision Switch' & that the device is managed by a bi-metallic strip round the 'knob', at a variable distance, based on distance from the rotation centre, around the circumference. If that's incorrect, then the entire theory falls at the first hurdle & I shall beat a hasty & apologetic retreat ;)

I have to admit I really know nothing about this technically - however… if the lever below is how you select your temperature, then currently it's set at 'hottest'. If you move it towards coldest, the "knob" above will first present its open face to the 'Precision Switch' then eventually the opposite end of the scale.

I'd say the "knob" is misaligned.

By way of illustration, & to make this easier for my limited Photoshop skills, first I roughly perspective corrected the image

[image]

Then 'turned the dial'

[image]

Isn't that going to break contact with the 'Precision Switch'?

I suppose a quick confirmation would be to see if a neighbour will let you photograph theirs to check the alignment. Saves getting building maintenance out again to scratch their chins.

Comment: Good catch, sir!

Comment: Very nice photoshopping ;)